# How to determine which permissions a shiro user has

Tags: java, shiro

I have to deal with an application which is secured by apache shiro.
I'm quite new to this framework. As far as I can see, I can check single rights via `subject.isPermitted()`, e.g.

```
Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
[...]
subject.isPermitted("$RightString");
```

For logging purposes I need the complete list of user rights as a String. And I do not want to iterate over the list of rights and check everytime, whether `subject.isPermitted()` is `true`

Is there any shortcut to this problem?

**Edit:**

Further Information:

- Application is a Spring 4 Application
- realm is defined in in application context as a bean

  ```
   <bean id="PRODUCTNAMERealm" class="de.PATHFROMPRODUCT_PRODUCTNAMEJdbcRealm">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
       <property name="schema" value="${PRODUCTNAME.schema}"/>
   </bean>
  ```

  so i could inject it if needed.

Comment: @sallu Realm information added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is no out of the box way to do this, be we worked around this by registering the user permissions on the session. We are using a custom realm implementation and our permissions are stored in the database.

In our custom realm class:

```
@Override
public AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
    Set<String> permissionsSet = //logic to get the permissions here

    info.addStringPermissions(permissionsSet);

    SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession().setAttribute("permissions", permissionsSet);
    return info;
}
```

Now retrieving the permissions is just a matter of calling:

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession().getAttribute("permissions");
```

Another way would be to inject your custom realm where you need the info and have the bean make getAuthorizationInfo public.

```
@Override
public AuthorizationInfo getAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    return super.getAuthorizationInfo(principals);
}

....

yourRealm.getAuthorizationInfo(SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipals()).getStringPermissions();
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you right: I have to get the source of the implementation of the custom realm class (in my case the extension of JdbcRealm) and I will have two chioces - if your code is right: a) put the permissions into the session and later retrieve it from there and b) what your code suggests: just get the AuthorizationInfo. There should be a getter. Unfortunately I have to wait till Monday. But I'll check that out and let you know.

Comment: Yes. Getting hold of the AuthorizationInfo would also work as it has a getStringPermission method giving you a set of all perms. We don't use that way however in our project. I don't think there is an easy way to get it as this object is only used in realms and it is never exposed directly.

Comment: I now see you are using spring so you can also inject the jdbc realm and indeed get the AuthorizationInfo object, adjusted my answer for this.

Comment: I accept your answer, because it should work. But as I realized, my root problem has shifted in an unexpected direction, so I do not need to resolve the user rigths.Tank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Shiro is related to only security, authority, etc of current user not to the whole user base. You can use your standard SQL queries to retrieve users permissions.

Comment: We are storing indeed the user-rights in a db. So if I'm interested in a users's rights, I could query the DB. But what I've not mentioned is the context or the purpose for what I am doing this. Currently we have problems in a Shiro/Cluster-scenario, where it seems, that Shirosession "forgets" users/rights. And to debug that case, I wanted to trace in certain cases, what user is logged in, and what rights does Shiro associate with this special user. Somewhere is a hole in our setup and at present I do not know where.

Answer (score 1):

you may override function getAuthorizationInfo in own AuthorizingRealm implementation

```
public class LoginPasswordRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {
    @Override
    public AuthorizationInfo getAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals){
        return super.getAuthorizationInfo(principals);
    }
}
```

and then user it:

```
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
LoginPasswordRealm realm = (LoginPasswordRealm)securityManager.getRealms().iterator().next();
AuthorizationInfo authorizationInfo = realm.getAuthorizationInfo(currentUser.getPrincipals());
authorizationInfo.getStringPermissions().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: which version are you using? I have no "securityManager.getRealms()" ?

Comment: to vished2000: 
shiro-core 1.2.4